# Jenkins Pipeline Copy Artifact to Local tomcat instance

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, copy, jenkins-pipeline, artifact

**Using Jenkins pipeline I am not able to copy artifact to a local tomcat instance**

I tried using *CopyArtifact* provided by JenkinsPipeline

*Syntax*: copyArtifacts(projectName: 'sourceproject'); - but it is not working

```
stage('Deploy to Tomcat Server'){
      copyArtifacts /Users/web/.jenkins/workspace/app/target/myweb-0.0.5.war /Users/web/apache-tomcat-9.0.16/webapps/
   }

Not able to copy artifact to tomcat webapps directory

Error:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 32: unexpected token: . @ line 32, column 33.
         copyArtifacts Users/web/.jenkins/workspace/app/target/myweb-0.0.5.war /Users/web/apache-tomcat-9.0.16/webapps/
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be (please refer [to documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin#CopyArtifactPlugin-Pipelinesyntax))

```
stage('Deploy to Tomcat Server') {
    copyArtifacts('project_name') {
        includePatterns('*.xml', '*.properties')
        excludePatterns('test.xml', 'test.properties')
        targetDirectory('files')
        flatten()
        optional()
        buildSelector {
            latestSuccessful(true)
        }
    }
}
```